# Connect from a Docker container to port of another docker container

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

I have two docker containers running on a linux host.

One with a DATABASE and one with an APPLICATION.

How can I connect from container APPLICATION to container DATABASE port 5432?

For example:
I start DATABASE container and bind port 5432 to hosts localhost with "-p5432:5432. But how can I acces this port from APPLICATION? I cannot bind port 5432 to host localhost because this port is now already used.

Docker version 1.12.6

### update

I used now

```
sudo docker network create --subnet=172.20.0.0/16 --gateway=172.20.0.100   --ip-range=172.20.1.0/24 my-network
sudo docker run --name postgres  --network=my-network --ip=172.20.0.10 -d postgres
sudo docker run --name application --network=my-network --ip=172.20.0.15 -d application
```

and configured app in APPLICATION container to look for ip 172.20.0.10

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/

Comment: You should look into docker-compose.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use docker networks, easy to achieve with [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/). In my example you can point from your `app` container to `postgres-container` as this: `postgres-container:5432`

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: postgres
    command: sh -c 'sleep 10; echo \\l | PGPASSWORD=mysecretpassword psql -U postgres -h postgres-container'
  postgres-container:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
```

Command:

```
docker-compose up
```

Output:

```
Attaching to postgresql_app_1, postgresql_postgres-container_1
(...)
postgres-container_1  | server started
(...)
app_1                 |                                  List of databases
app_1                 |    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
app_1                 | -----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
app_1                 |  postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
app_1                 |  template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
app_1                 |            |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
app_1                 |  template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
app_1                 |            |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
app_1                 | (3 rows)
app_1                 |
```

Comment: This is not working with my version:
    ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use docker link to link to running containers ... like below and use alias name as ip address. You can do same using docker-compose as well.

   $ docker run -d -P --name application --link db-image:db application-image

use 'db' as host name in your application.

2. You can also give your host ip to application container as db end point. It will work.

Comment: Links are considered deprecated. See the warning here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/